# What is this Boron Compound called?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What would this aromatic boron compound be called?

[image]

Comment: Label the atoms.

Comment: Is this [1H-Borepin](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.26666607.html)

Comment: @blue I used CPK coloring code for atoms. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPK_coloring

Comment: @PrittBalagopal You should mention that in your question to avoid confusion. I wasn't sure what colouring scheme you were using.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*, heteromonocyclic compounds with up to and including ten ring members are named by the extended [Hantzsch–Widman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.H02737) system. According to P-68.1.1.3.2, this also applies to heterocyclic parent hydrides containing Group 13 (boron group) atoms.

The Hantzsch-Widman system stem for an unsatured 7-membered ring is “epine”. Therefore, the preferred name for the compound that is given in the question is **1​*H*-borepine.**
The name 1​*H*-1-boracyclohepta-2,4,6-triene is not recommended.

Comment: Unsaturated or fully conjugated 7-member ring?  Do we use epine for the cycloalkene formulated C7H12?

Comment: @OscarLanzi H-W system is for heterocycles, not alkenes.

Comment: Then presumably the words "fully conjugated" should be used instead of "unsaturated".

Answer (score 6):

If the black coloured are carbon atoms and the white coloured are hydrogen atoms, and the pink one is Boron. Then it should be **[1H-Borepine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/14970100#section=Top)**.

[image]
<sup>[[Source: Chemspider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.26666607m.html)]</sup>

See [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64054/why-is-1h-borepine-aromatic) for why it is aromatic.

Comment: There is a standard color code for ball and stick models.  True, carbon = black, hydrogen = white, boron = that pretty pink color. Some others :  oxygen = red, nitrogen = blue, chlorine = yellowish green like the gas.

Comment: @Mesentery Thanks for your answer. There is in fact a color code for atoms. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPK_coloring